# Why are some equal expressions more equal than others?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
n1 = 1/3 (2 + (-Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[(2 π)/9])/(Sqrt[3] Cos[π/9] - Sin[π/9]));
n2 = 1/2 + Sin[π/18]/(3 Cos[(2 π)/9] + Sqrt[3] Sin[(2 π)/9]);
n3 = 2/3 (1 - Cos[4 π/9]);
```

These three expressions are numerically equivalent. How can I coax *Mathematica* to simplify the first two into the third? `FullSimplify` only returns the original forms.

Comment: It's at least worth pointing out that the form produced by `RootReduce` is the same for all three: `RootReduce /@ {n1, n2, n3}`

Comment: Is that a political question  ;-)  ?

Comment: @Yves The title, while amusing, doesn't describe the problem.  Perhaps we should change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that MMA aggressively evaluates `n3` to `2/3 (1 - Sin[\[Pi]/18])`, 
so I assume this is `n3`.

This is the best I could do:

```
ExpToTrig[ToRadicals[Root[MinimalPolynomial[n1, x], 2]] /. {
    1 + I Sqrt[3] :> 2 (-1)^(1/3), 1 - I Sqrt[3] -> -2 (-1)^(2/3)}]

(* 2/3 - 2/3 Sin[π/18] *)
```

and

```
ExpToTrig[ToRadicals[Root[MinimalPolynomial[n2, x], 2]] /. {
    1 + I Sqrt[3] :> 2 (-1)^(1/3), 1 - I Sqrt[3] -> -2 (-1)^(2/3)}]

(* 2/3 - 2/3 Sin[π/18] *)
```

Comment: Excellent work around, thank you.

Comment: @Phillip why note vote for his answer in that case?

Comment: Ok, how do I vote for an answer?